# difference between ireports Internal preview & pdf preview

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I have designed the reports in Jaspersoft iRreport Designer 4.0.2

In Internal preview it shows the report in specified font(calibri). Its design and alignment of elements is proper.
But in PDF preview its font,alignment of elements are different.

Answer (score 2):

- Try to set ***`pdfFontName`*** and ***`isPdfEmbedded`*** font settings.

The sample:

```xml
<font fontName="Arial" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
```

The ***PDF embedded*** flag specifies whether an external TrueType font file should be included
in the *PDF* file.

- Another way is to use the `Font Extensions` mechanism. This method is recommended by vendor.

The example:

You can generate the font extension for *Calibri* font with *iReport*. The result will be the *jar* file.

The config file (from the generated jar package) will be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fontFamilies>
   <fontFamily name="Calibri">
       <normal><![CDATA[fonts/calibri.ttf]]></normal>
       <bold><![CDATA[fonts/calibrib.ttf]]></bold>
       <italic><![CDATA[fonts/calibrii.ttf]]></italic>
       <boldItalic><![CDATA[fonts/calibriz.ttf]]></boldItalic>
       <pdfEncoding><![CDATA[Identity-H]]></pdfEncoding>
       <pdfEmbedded><![CDATA[true]]></pdfEmbedded>
       <exportFonts>
               <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html"><![CDATA[CalibriHtml]]></export>
       </exportFonts>
       <locales>
               <locale><![CDATA[en]]></locale>
       </locales>
   </fontFamily>
</fontFamilies>
```

The snippet from *jrxml* file for demonstrating the usage of a new font extension:

```xml
<staticText>
    <reportElement x="215" y="26" width="100" height="20"/>
    <textElement>
        <font fontName="Calibri"/>
    </textElement>
    <text><![CDATA[Static text]]></text>
</staticText>
```

You can use [this link](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fonts) for detailed information about using fonts in *JasperReports*.

Comment: <font fontName="Calibri" pdfFontName="CALIBRI.TTF" isPdfEmbedded="true" pdfEncoding ="Identity-H"/>How can I use "Calibri" font ?